# C++ Hazelcast client-based code migration from v3.12.1 to v5.3.0 documentaiton

Tags: c++, hazelcast

Rebuilding the existing C++ Hazelcast client-based code, that works fine under v3.12.1 binaries, with gcc 11.4.1 on Amazon Linux 2023 and the Hazelcast 64-bit library `libhazelcast-cpp-client.so.5.3` built from sources off of v5.3.0 with the same compiler on the same OS and the corresponding header files, fails with errors like `No such file or directory: #include <hazelcast/client/ILock.h>`.

We were able to resolve such a compilation error with `HazelcastClient.h` header file, which became `hazelcast_client.h` (with a corresponding change in the class name).

However, we cannot find any actionable description on how to deal with the absence of the `ILock.h` header file in v5.3.0 C++ code and the corresponding class that was defined in that file.

Question: where is the documentations that 1) spells out all the breaking changes between 3.12.x and 5.x exclusively for C++ clients and 2) describes the ways to fix these breaking changes?

Thank you in advance.